# Windsor Dependency injection with properties

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a windsor container and windsor doesnt inject my property. The curious thing is with `ServiceA` the dependency is resolved but not with the component.

```
Container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
Container.Register(Component.For<PublisherService>().AsWcfService());
Container.Register(Component.For<IExecutionProgram>().ImplementedBy<ExecutionProgram>());
Container.Register(Component.For<IValidationProgram>().Instance(Factory.CreateProgramA()));
Container.Register(Component.For<RunnerService>().AsWcfService());
```

This is my `Factory` (All the Dependencies implement the same interface and all SubDependencies implement an other shared Interface):

```
public static class Factory{
  public static IValidationProgram CreateProgramA(){
    var program = new ValidationProgram(
       new DependencyA(
         new SubDependencyA(),
         new SubDependencyB(),
       ),
       new DependencyB()
    );
  }
}
```

In my `RunnerService` the `IExecutionProgram`, Property will be resolved.
In my `IValidationProgram`, I created the `IExecutionProgram` will not be resolved.
Properties are public in both Implementations.
What did I do wrong?

**EDIT:**
I added the factory. These Dependencies are all Interfaces and I need specific implementations for a program. So in general I would like to switch easily between programA or programB. I looked into type Facilities like  Marwijn supposed, but I cant get the hang of it. How do I use it in my case?

Comment: You are manually creating a new instance of `ValidationProgram`, so this will not give the IOC a chance bind the public dependencies.

Comment: So I can only use the IOC when I Inject everything?

Comment: No, but if you expect a dependency to be resolved automatically, then the type that contains the dependency needs to be resolved by the IOC.  By using `.Instance`, you are effectively saying to the IOC, "back off, I've got this one".

Comment: The `new ValidationProgram()` is a Factory in reality (I shortend it for the example). So How can I tell the IOC that it should resolve the dependencies? Or am I using a wrong approach?

Comment: You should in your factory method inject this property by yourself. or use container.Resolve instead of new.

Comment: For factories first take a look at windsors typedfactory facility. It will do for 95% of the cases.